# Android:Auto-login for Instagram API

Tags: android, oauth, instagram

I am building a simple application that connects to my Instagram account, retrieve the images and show them in a listView.

The application is working fine. I used [this project](https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-instagram-oauth) to do the authorization part and then I added into it the image retrieving and listView part.

Now my only problem is that each time I run the application I have to type my username and password, Is there a way to avoid that ? I want to simply run the application and see it fill the listView automatically from the images in my Instagram account.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you retrieving and saving the auth token after initial login, and then using the auth token in future logins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. first register  your app
2. After register your app.Your info look like this.
3. Client ID   f6a90a150e6a4c66ad7926f70e73a6ea
4. Client Secret   6e9e15bd4f0e427d8da3fe9e0bf65c8d
5. Website URL     http://www.ntz.com/
6. Redirect URI    http://www.ntz.com/instagram//access-token
7. https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=f6a90a150e6a4c66ad7926f70e73a6ea&redirect_uri=http://www.ntz.com/instagram//access-token&response_type=code
8. paste it in your browser.
9. Now you have to authenticate your app.
10. click ok